# What are the Takeoff Minimums for aircraft operating under Part 91?

Tags: faa-regulations, instrument-flight-rules, takeoff

What are the IFR Takeoff Minimums for aircraft operating under Part 91?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the Instrument Procedures Handbook (FAA-H-8083-16A) page 1-8:

> "Aircraft operating under 14 CFR Part 91 are not required to comply
>   with established takeoff minimums. Legally, a zero/zero departure may
>   be made, but it is never advisable."

Comment: Does that include only standard minimums, or does it also extend to minima prescribed under §97? James Albright says that pilots must still adhere to minima prescribed under §97 when operating under §91. There is substantial debate on this.

Comment: @jonathan Walters.  If a pilot departed with 0/0 (ceiling and visibility 0), what rule would be violated under Part 91? There are no rules against this as shown above in Devel07's answer.  Should be no debate unless a published rule prohibits it.

Comment: I was surprised by this when I learned it, and had to share. The statement in the handbook seems very clear and it was from the 2015 version.

Comment: James Albright argues essentially that the operation is also under §97, not only §91. A bit of a grey area, but I am inclined to disagree with him on this, as much as I respect his opinion and body of work as a whole.